# SonarQube cannot parse TEST-report.xml which contains any failures

Tags: swift, xcode, sonarqube

How to send the XML report to SonarQube? I mean, while the `TEST-report.xml` file contains any failures, the import operation fails. I got an error:

```
Running SonarQube using SonarQube Runner.17:18:18.452 ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.parse(DecimalFormat.java:2030)
    at java.text.NumberFormat.parse(NumberFormat.java:383)
    ...
```

The `TEST-report.xml` file (JUnit) contains something like:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<testsuites name='X UITests.xctest' tests='12' failures='3'>
  <testsuite name='X.MoreViewTests' tests='1' failures='1'>
    <testcase classname='X.MoreViewTests' name='testSucceed_allAction'>
      <failure message='XCTAssertTrue failed'>X UITests/Cases/Bottom Navigation/MoreViewTests.swift:212</failure>
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name='X.OrderViewTests' tests='1' failures='0'>
    <testcase classname='X.OrderViewTests' name='testSucceed_allAction' time='68.570'/>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

But when I removed the failure lines, becomes:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<testsuites name='X UITests.xctest' tests='12' failures='3'>
  <testsuite name='X.OrderViewTests' tests='1' failures='0'>
    <testcase classname='X.OrderViewTests' name='testSucceed_allAction' time='68.570'/>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

It works. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML report is invalid (doesn't meet [the Surefire XML format requirements](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/xsd/surefire-test-report-3.0.xsd)).

`testsuite` required parameters:

- `name` - Full class name of the test for non-aggregated testsuite documents. Class name without the package for aggregated testsuites documents
- `tests` - The total number of tests in the suite
- `failures` - The total number of tests in the suite that failed. A failure is a test which the code has explicitly failed by using the mechanisms for that purpose. e.g., via an assertEquals
- `errors` - The total number of tests in the suite that errored. An errored test is one that had an unanticipated problem. e.g., an unchecked throwable; or a problem with the implementation of the test
- `skipped` - The total number of ignored or skipped tests in the suite

The exception starts with `DecimalFormat.parse`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.parse(DecimalFormat.java:2030)
    at java.text.NumberFormat.parse(NumberFormat.java:383)
```

which means that the XML report parser couldn't parse a number. You have two missing parameters: `errors` and `skipped`. I don't know how you generate these reports (which JUnit version etc.), but probably the used tool is outdated or miss-configured.